# Setting UITextField Background in Attribute Inspector

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

According to the documentation, background property is

> The image that represents the background appearance of the text field
>   when it is enabled.

In the attribute inspector there is a *Background* Dropdown with a lot of items to choose from, but no matter what I choose, nothing happens if done for the UITextField. If done for a UIButton, it is working fine.

Update: the question is not about setting the background color in code. It is about why does choosing any item from the drop down in attribute inspector does not have any effect for the UITextField.

Answer (score 0):

You can change UItextfield background color through code like this:

```
textField.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
```

Comment: I know. The question is not about setting the background color in code. It is about why does choosing any item from the drop down in attribute inspector does not have any effect.